Bind dynamic data to Apexcharts series using ASP.NET and C#
I'm trying to bind dynamic data to Apex Charts series but values are not rendering in chart.
This is my code:
[WebMethod]
public static List<object> GetRequestsCount()
{
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
    List<int> totalCount = new List<int>();
    totalCount.Add(99);
    chartData.Add(totalCount.ToArray());
    return chartData;
}

$(function () {
   "use strict";

    // chart 1
   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../portaldashboard.aspx/GetRequestsCount',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess_,
        error: OnErrorCall_
    });

    function OnErrorCall_(repo) {
        alert(repo);
    }

    function OnSuccess_(reponse) {
        var aData = reponse.d;
        alert(reponse.d); // value is appearing in popup
        console.log(aData[1]);
        var options = {
            series: aData[1],
            chart: {
                height: 180,
                type: 'radialBar',
                toolbar: {
                    show: false
                }
            },'

Kindly help to get this binding of the data to chart from C# working.
